# Как добавить условие для проверки наличия ID в таблице?

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени.

Не могу разобраться с одной вещью.

Допустим, ID = любое число, и есть CASH = тоже число.

Сейчас стоит условие: если оно выполняется, то в базу заносится строка с данным ид и определённым cash=20.

Нужно добавить ещё одно условие, чтоб проверялось, есть ли такой ID уже в таблице, и если есть, то к тому cash, который у него произвести +20.

Comment: За вас код написать? Что у вас не получается?

Comment: @Sneeska, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Запрос

```
INSERT INTO table (id,cash) VALUES({$id},{$cash}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cash=cash+20
```

Чтобы все работало, необходимо, чтобы id был определен как `PRIMARY` или `UNIQUE`. Подробности [тут](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/insert.html).